# angular div (clickOutside) is called when clicking input inside of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using (clickOutside) directive with div, and it is called when I click input element inside div.

```
<div class="col-4 align-self-center" (click)="setMethod(true)"
     (clickOutside)="setMethod(false)" >
    <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="accent" >
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               *ngIf="activeTitle"
               [(ngModel)]="title" />
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the **(blur)** event instead of using **(clickOutside)**. Maybe that would do the trick for you?

Note that the blur event fires when the component loses focus. This means that in order for **blur** to fire, the HTML element needs to be focused in the first place. E.g. the user has to have clicked on it with the mouse. You can call the [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) method on that element when your user clicks anywhere inside it, thereby ensuring that **blur** will be fired when the element loses focus.

E.g.:

```
<div
    class="col-4 align-self-center"
    (click)="setMethod(true)"
    (blur)="setMethod(false)"
>
    <button
        type="button"
        mat-raised-button color="accent"
    >
        <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            *ngIf="activeTitle"
            [(ngModel)]="title"
        />
    </button>
</div>
```